# access the user's password in asp.net

Tags: ldap

I'm writing a small asp.net app that passes control to a 3rd-party app via an https post.  The 3rd party must authenticate against our LDAP server.  To facilitate our Single Sign-on process, I need to pass the user's ID and password in the post, but I'm not sure how to access the password.  Any ideas?  Sorry if this seems rudimentary, I'm new to the .NET world.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just think of the security risks that could be involved in letting any authenticated user pull a password of another object in the directory.

Some directory systems do allow you to pull a password hash out of it, but that won't help you. Others will let you store it in a reversible encryption scheme, but this introduces huge security risks.

You probably need to get with your IT department to see if your directory server even supports pulling passwords, what's involved to get access to that data, and what the security risks are.

Comment: Just to be clear, the app would only be able to send the password of THE CURRENTLY LOGGED IN USER, and it would be posted via HTTPS.  I'm thinking it's not possible for .net to extract the password, but I wanted to verify this before moving on to other alternatives.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your LDAP server is badly misconfigured, it won't even have the password, only a hash. You need to rethink.